# eglot code completion for C# Godot?

Tags: csharp-mode, eglot

I have recently started using eglot for code completion. I was able to install [Omnisharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/) on my system and get eglot to run for my `.cs` files. However eglot does not seem to be aware of any of the `Godot` namespace functions, classes, or types. It display an error about unknown symbols and cannot find definitions.

As a test I used Visual Studio Code and it was able to code complete Godot c# types without any Godot extensions installed.

Looking inside my project directory I see a `.sln` file as well as `.mono` directory with its `assemblies` directory containing several `GodotSharp` c# files like `.dll` and `.xml`. I am assuming that the `.sln` file combined with the `GodotSharp.{dll,pdb,xml}` files are what Visual Studio Code uses to learn about Godot c# types.

My question is: How do I configure eglot and Omnisharp to know about the Godot c# types? I see in the [Omnisharp documentation](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/blob/master/doc/Using-Omnisharp.md#solutions) it mentions pointing the Omnisharp binary to a `.sln` file to use c# solutions. So I tried modifying my `eglot-server-programs` variable to launch Omnisharp this way:

```lisp
(setq eglot-server-programs (remove '(csharp-mode "omnisharp" "-lsp") eglot-server-programs))
  (add-to-list 'eglot-server-programs '(csharp-mode "omnisharp" "*.sln" "-lsp"))
```

I also tried variations with `omnisharp -s *.sln -lsp` and `omnisharp myproject.sln -lsp`. However with all these attempts eglot fails to connect to Omnisharp.

How might I configure eglot and Omnisharp to know about Godot c# types?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to do 2 things to solve this issue. Item #2 might not be relevant but I want to post it just in case it is and others have this issue.

1. Ensure that the OmniSharp binary is being run in your project's directory. Due to the way I had installed OmniSharp (on Linux so it was a bit custom through a package manager) the OmniSharp binary was being run with a working directory of `/usr/local/bin`. This meant it couldn't find my solution file because I was giving a relative path. I figured this out when I saw an error message from the OmniSharp LSP server which said it couldn't find the `myproject.sln` file. Once I editted my install to make OmniSharp run in my project directory I was able to get eglot working.
2. I installed the Mono version of OmnisSharp. I'm not quite sure if this is absolutely required, but I think it makes sense because Godot uses Mono and I assume there is some formatting difference of Mono vs .NET dll files which might have caused the Godot dll files to not be read properly.

[image: Eglot docs for godot type]